# CLICOLOR env variable

Tags: environment-variables, ls, colors

I have read about CLICOLOR that enables colors e.g. in `ls`. Is it only used by `ls` or is it used by other applications as well?

Maybe related question: Is there a universal env variable to enable or disable colors in shell tools?

Comment: Should be just **`TERM`**, but doing that would preclude the opportunity for developers to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some searches, I found that `clicolor` only used in ls.c in the source for FreeBSD:

https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/search?q=clicolor

The other uses are in the LS manual.

And no, there is no universal variable. Each tool is different. OpenBSD ls doesn't even use clicolor either.